# WPF chart SelectedItem binding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, wpftoolkit

I have a chart which I would like to allow the user to select a data point which will select the corresponding item in a datagrid via view model.

I am binding to the `SelectedItem` on the `LineSeries`, `mode TwoWay` but it is not firing off the setter in my view model at all although the getter is clearly working as selecting a value in the datagrid highlights the correct data point.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart>
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Status"
                                IndependentValuePath="DateTaken"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding OverallStatus}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrendPoint, Mode=TwoWay}">
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

What's wrong with my chart???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the binding on your LineSeries is fine, but the WPF-Toolkit LineSeries has a flag `IsSelectionEnabled` which is false by default. If you set this flag then you will see the binding working. Add `IsSelectionEnabled="True"` to your LineSeries
Try this:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart>
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Status"
                                IndependentValuePath="DateTaken"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding OverallStatus}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrendPoint, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```